# Detecting image upload event with a chrome browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am trying to create a chrome browser extension that acts in the background when an image file is uploaded on any page. My question is how do I go about detecting file/image uploads in chrome? I've been looking through the chrome API documentation and can't seem to pinpoint the right API for this job.

The basic functionality I want to implement is that this extension gets fired up in the background when an image file is uploaded on any page, does something to the image data and returns it to the user. I'm trying to get the first part down of detecting the uploading event on the page and grabbing said file. I'm just having trouble tracking down the right API('s) for this task.